# Grouping data and presenting in a table from an api

Tags: php, for-loop

I am returning data in a for each loop  in 2 strings from an api like this:

eg $key = "2012 q4"; and $value = "34542";

```
*2012 q4* **34542**
*2012 q3* **35383**
*2012 q2* **36171**
*2012 q1* **36926**
*2011 q4* **37913**
*2011 q3* **38740**
*2011 q2* **39641**
*2011 q1* **40548**
```

I would then like to display it in this format in a table

```
year      q1           q2         q3        q4
2012      36926        36171      35383     34542
2011      40548        39641      38740     37913
```

This is all I have so far, literally clueless on how to go from here.

```
foreach($hm["quarterly_tax"]["licensed"] as  $key => $value) {
echo $key." ".$value."<br />";
}
```

I could work out the year and quarter by doing this I guess:

```
$year = substr($key, 0, 4);
$quater = substr($key, 5, 7);
```

but stuck from then on...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you write the API? Because it doesn't seem like an official API as there are bettwer ways to transfer strings like XML or JSON. If you did you'll have more luck reading about the above formats.

Comment: Not my api, I retrieve the data in JSON then decode it.
Comes in like this:

string(4163) "{"quarterly_tax":{"licensed":{"2012 q4":34542,"2012 q3":35383,"2012 q2":36171,"2012 q1":36926,"2011 q4":37913,"2011 q3":38740,"2011 q2":39641,"2011 q1":40548

think i would still have the same issue though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not tested it, but should give you the some idea for the logic.

```
 foreach($hm["quarterly_tax"]["licensed"] as  $key => $value) {
$year = substr($key, 0, 4);
$quater = substr($key, 5, 7);
$arr[$year][$q][] = $value; 
}
```

Now you will have an 3d array that's sorted per possible values, should be something like this : `

```
    Array
(
    [2012] => Array
        (
            [q1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 36926
                    [1] => 12345
                )

            [q2] =>  Array
                (
                    [0] => 36171
                )

            [q3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 35383
                )

        )

    [2011] = Array
        (
            [q1] = Array
                (
                    [0] =40548
                )

        )

)
```

Which is much easier to handle, since it's sorted to the way you need it, now u can just output the table accordingly.